# why do I get "The type GraphicsContext from module javafx.graphics may not be accessible to clients due to missing 'requires transitive'" warning?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, javafx

Whenever I create a GraphicsContext object in my JavaFX application, it creates an error that reads:

> The type GraphicsContext from module javafx.graphics may not be accessible to clients due to missing 'requires transitive'

Here's a small example of code which causes the warning/ error:

```
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;

    public Factory(GraphicsContext gc) {
        super();
        this.gc = gc;
    }
```

The GraphicsContext is underlined in the warning colour, and has 3 quick fixes suggested by eclipse. 2 of them include adding @SuppressWarnings which does not fix the problem at all and the other "Configure Problem Serverity" which I think just tells eclipse to not worry about the issue.

This code works perfectly when ran in eclipse but when I export as a runnable JAR file, the file closes immediately. I would like the classes to be accessible to clients as GraphicsContexts are funsamental to my application.

I also get the same error when I use the JavaFX class stage.

> The type Stage from module javafx.graphics may not be accessible to clients due to missing 'requires transitive'

I am using eclipse and jdk-16

How/where in my program do I include 'requires transitive'? Or is there a differnt problem hidden by this warning?

Comment: I think this is talking about an entry in the 'module-info.java' for the [Java Module System](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html)

Comment: Regarding the JAR file not launching properly, try launching it from the console in order to see the error.

Answer (score 7):

If you are set up as a modular project, you should have a `module-info.java` file directly in your **/src** folder.

Here is an example of contents of a module-info.java file, from the [openjfx.io Getting Started documentation](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Eclipse):
[image]

As you can see, the word "transitive" was added to the line for javafx.graphics.

Comment: This should be flagged as the answer.  I was surprised that maven didn't pick up the transitive dependency.  The app still ran fine.  A diagnostic showed the proper initialized type.  To really clean problems up, I had to add 'requires transitive javafx.base;' as well.